# How do I resize the text to "Shape to fit text" in Google Slides using AppScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

[image]

I have been trying to resize the rendered text to auto-fit, I searched through the docs, and videos but no luck. Would really appreciate any help.

[Gooogle AppScript Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides?authuser=1#format_shape_text)

The `updateTextAutoFit` function isn't working. The API is returning this error `Failed with error API call to slides.presentations.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[0].updateShapeProperties: The object (SLIDES_API1782835896_0) could not be found.`

```ts
function updateTextAutoFit(presentationId: string, objectId: string) {
  // You can specify the ID to use for the slide, as long as it's unique.
  const requests: GoogleAppsScript.Slides.Schema.Request[] = [
    {
      updateShapeProperties: {
        objectId: objectId,
        fields: "autofit",
        shapeProperties: {
          // @ts-ignore
          autofit: {
            autofitType: "SHAPE_AUTOFIT",
          },
        },
        // 'slideLayoutReference': {
        //   'predefinedLayout': 'TITLE_AND_TWO_COLUMNS'
        // }
      },
    },
  ];
  try {
    const slide = Slides.Presentations?.batchUpdate(
      { requests: requests },
      presentationId
    );
    return slide;
  } catch (e: any) {
    // TODO (developer) - Handle Exception
    Logger.log("Failed with error %s", e.message);
  }
}

const titleText = createTextBox({
  slide,
  text: title,
  fontSize: 28,
  isBold: true,
  position: titlePosition,
  presentationId,
});

updateTextAutoFit(presentationId, id);
```